# How to bower install the latest footable release?

Tags: bower, bower-install, footable

I'm installing plugins using bower, but bower only downloads [Footable](https://github.com/bradvin/FooTable) v2.0.1, not the latest release of v2.0.1.5.

I've tried:

```
bower install --save-dev footable
bower install --save-dev footable#2.0.1.x
```

Both these download v2.0.1, I want the latest tagged release of v2 (v2.0.1.5).

Using #2.0.1.x also gave the error "ENORESTARGET: Tag/Branch 2.0.1.x does not exist".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bower package versions should follow [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/).
In short, a valid semantic version is in the form of `MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH`.
2.0.1.5, for example, is not a valid semantic version.

You can get a list of available versions for a package by running the following command:

```
bower info footable
```

For footable you the results are:

```
Available versions:
  - 2.0.1
  - 2.0.0
  - 0.5.0
  - 0.1.0
```

Comment: That explains it! Can I use bower to stay updated or is it impossible for plugins using 4-part versions?

Comment: You can force Bower to download a specific 4-part version by specifying the exact version. Other than that, it looks like all non semver versions are being filtered from the available version list (after looking inside GitResolver.js)